# Calculate checksum for the string

Tags: java, twos-complement

I have to compute checksum for more than 2 characters in my java code.
If its' `HI` - > ASCII value is

```
72 - 01001000
73 - 01001001
--------------
     10010001 
     01101110 - 1's complement (110 in decimal) - checksum
```

I'm passing 72, 73 and 110. If i debug the code, 72 + 73 would result in -111 in my code. If I compute in decimal format its 145. Why is it -111 ?

```
byte[] bytes = "01001000 01001001 01101110".getBytes();
for(byte b: bytes) {
            sum += b;
        }
```

Comment: And now the big question (out of nowhere): Where is your code and why do you think we can aswer your question without it?

Comment: It's negative if you calculating using a `byte`, since byte stores signed values ranging from `-128` to `127`, hence `145` overflows and becomes `-111`.